# Issue using \ensuremath in glossaries

Tags: math-mode, glossaries

I'm trying to get the `\ensuremath` function to work within `glossaries` for the following:

```
\newglossaryentry{CSPB}{name={CSP\ensuremath{\parallel}B},
  description={A hybrid formal language combining CSP and the B-Method},sort=CSPB}
```

However I get an error message:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 120.
```

If I take the `\ensuremath{\parallel}` out there is no problem. 
Any ideas why this isn't working as the manual suggests?

Comment: Try `\protect\parallel`.

Comment: `\ensuremath` is inappropriate here in any case, you would be better just to use `$\parallel$`. If you are in text mode this will do the right thing. If for some reason you were already in math mode the `CSP` would have been set with an inappropriate font and having `\ensuremath` around the `\parallel` would not fix that.

Answer (score 4):

You should read the 'sanitize' part of the glossaries manual. The `name` key gets sanitized by default. You either need to `\protect` your entry or give the package option `sanitize={name=false}`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `\parallel` is not supported - implemented using `\mid\mid` instead

Comment: `\parallel` works for me.